# R-Project sent me my unencrypted password in plain text

Tags: r, email, security, encryption, passwords

I just received an email from the R-Project, an email subscription service that sends out emails for R question, and they sent me my password, unencrypted, in plain text. Is this a security flaw, and should I immediately contact them and change my password? I've never had a service send me my password without even asking.

Comment: https://plaintextoffenders.com/about/

Comment: Are you talking about the password for the mailing list subscription? Setting aside the question of whether it is acceptable behavior, the software used (`mailman`) is common and known to have this behavior. It explicitly says on the subscription page: `Do not use a valuable password as it will occasionally be emailed back to you in cleartext.`

Comment: Ok you make a fair point, but why do they do they do that?

Comment: @TimSmaluk I don't know for sure, but you can find discussion on this by googling `mailman password security` or the like. Newer mailman versions can store hashed passwords, so you could ask the website's administrator to upgrade and enable that feature. If you want to be safe, you should change your password everywhere you used the same one you gave in the mailing list subscription.